# Clojure/Ring how to get post parameters in submit order

Tags: clojure, ring

I have a very complex form. I need to get the post parameters from that form in the order they have been submitted. The application is created in ring/compojure.

All the parameters that I can get from ring request are preprocessed (grouped, sorted..)

How do I get the raw parameter list (preferably parsed to key/value vector or some other list)?

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more information about your project. What HTTP server are you using (http-kit, clj-http, aleph), and what middleware do you have applied in your project?

All parameter based things aren't actually part of the ring spec, but are handled by middleware (see https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Parameters), so it greatly depends on what bits you're currently pulling in.

I'm not aware of any ring middleware that currently exist that do you want, they all seem to parse the parameter list and put it into a hashmap, and if multiple parameters exist with the same key name, they make the value in the hashmap a vector of the items.

That all being said, I have to ask. **Why** do you need them in a particular order?

Comment: I was coming to the same conclusion that I was going to have to implement my own middleware but then I noticed that http body is not non-stateless and has already been read by other parameter middleware.. sigh. There are solutions to that but in the end I think I'll end up creating some kind of other solution that involves complex parameter naming scheme instead of using the order (tree order) which the parameters are submitted..

Comment: And about the reason, the form is a kind of editable dynamic tree structure with known parameter names so that's why I need the parameters in order. Otherwise I have to name the parameters based on some id-scheme and that is harder than parsing the tree from ordered list.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to create your own middleware. Use the wrap-param middleware as a guide. You just need to do your custom stuff at  https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/params.clj#L29

That said, I also be wary of expecting the params in a particular order as it will make brittle the client-server communication.